# Getting nil from dateFromString when converting string to date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Every time I try to pass a date string to the `dateFromString` function I get `nil`. I haven't read anywhere that things have changed since the iOS 7 update, but I am current on updates if that makes a difference on whether or not this still works the same way.

This is the code I'm using to create the date from string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
```

and my date string is `@"2015-08-22 13:00:00"`

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-08-22 13:00:00"];
return date;
```

The last line returns nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

With:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Since `hh` refers to the 12 hour clock and `HH` refers to the 24 hour clock.

Comment: You saved me by 'hh' and 'HH' difference , thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

`hh` represents hours in 12-hour-mode and 13 is out of range.

Replace `hh` with `HH` for 24-hour-mode

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem last week and I solved it with this code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateFromString.doubleValue];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

- Here you have a string named **dateFromString** because this is the object type for date which I recieve from server. This string is converted in double value and the date is calculated with time interval.
- I suppose you need this date to be shown in a label or text view or another UI element like this, and just because of that I converted the date into NSString to be easy to use it. This is what I have in **stringDate**.

Let me know if I have to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

smaller case letters for 12 hour clock and upper case for 24-hr. Change hh with HH.